# Sequential execution (form + ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need send a form with ajax, code next:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#id_ask").val(id),
    $("#id_text").val( $('#editor').markdownEditor('content') )
    console.log($("#id_text").val())
    ForumService.create_answer($("#myForm"), URL);
})
```

I get:

```
My content
POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/API/forum/answer/ 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

This mean, `id_text` value does not been sent.

So seen `$("#id_text").val( $('#editor').markdownEditor('content') )` is too slow and it execute after of `ForumService.create_answer(URL);`

How could fix that?

I tried with: `.change()` and `$.when()`

Thanks

### Update:

Ajax:

```
ForumService.create_answer = function (form, url)
{
    formData = new FormData($(form).get(0));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend :
            function( xhr ) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", JSON.parse($.session.get("Token")).token_type +" "+ JSON.parse($.session.get("Token")).access_token );
        }
...
        })
```

Payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryVPuu073tJX2oNFzh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ask"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryVPuu073tJX2oNFzh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"


------WebKitFormBoundaryVPuu073tJX2oNFzh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"


------WebKitFormBoundaryVPuu073tJX2oNFzh--
```

Comment: Where is the code that sends the AJAX request? We would need to see that. The 400 error could be caused by any number of reasons. You'd need to check your server logs to see exactly what the issue is in this case. Your theory of the `markdownEditor` call being too slow would rely on that method being asynchronous, which is highly unlikely.